# Pure virtual function call in C++

Tags: c++, gcc, pure-virtual

My application crashes with the message "pure virtual function called". I removed all the pure virtual functions and gave them an implementation `ASSERT(false);...` so it should at least tell me where it crashed. And, it doesn't. So there has to be another location with virtual functions, right?

How can I debug it without using a debugger?

Comment: **1.** How can we know, without seeing any code? **2.** Why "without using a debugger?"

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that message came from your runtime library (or compiler, or otherwise the C++ implementation itself) as opposed to a third-party library?

Comment: @Potatoswatter: I wanted to verify exactly this, so I removed all the pure virtual functions. Now I'm not sure if that's the proper way of doing it..

Comment: See http://www.artima.com/cppsource/pure_virtual.html ; apparently Sun Studio and Watcom produce this message. If you have no pure virtual functions of your own, then someone else must be defining one. Not much more to say given the information here.

Comment: @Angew: how about talking about concepts instead of code? If I have simple code to show, I probably would. And if I could use a debugger, I most probably would too.

Comment: Why can you not use a debugger?  You have the code in front of you, and so the ability to debug it.  We have no code, and so cannot debug it.  Does that concept make sense?

Comment: No, this concept doesn't make sense. This concept is usually used by code monkeys who don't think and are lost if the environment doesn't provide a debugger..

Comment: @duedl0r OK, but my apps are working, yours are not :)

Answer (score 4):

The most common cause of pure virtual function calls I happen to have fought with is:

- calling virtual functions on objects while destroying these objects.
- calling virtual functions on objects after copying only base class ( object slicing)

If you don't want to or cannot debug, you should at least put some trace/log to find when/what's happening. I suggest you put some trace in the destructors of some objects.

When derived objects are destroyed, the virtual table no longer points to derived member functions.
ANd if you call a function on the remaining interface of your object, you then can have pure function calls since the derived objects is no longer, only remains its superclass.

Comment: Ok, but if every object has an implementation, then there shouldn't be a pure virtual function call, even inside destructors, no? I investigate my destructors and report back, thx.

Comment: To your question "no?" the answer is no. I have also edited my answer and I have added the case of object slicing, that can produces pure virtual call. Same problem: the derived part of the object is no longer accessible.